# Passing Delegate into MbUnit RowTest?

Tags: c#, mbunit

I've got an MbUnit unit test that I want to use Row tests for, and as one of the parameters, I want to pass a delegate.  So something like this:

```
public delegate object MyDelegate();
[Test]
[Row(SpecificDelegate)]
public void MyTest(MyDelegate specificDelegate)
{
    // DO TEST
}
public object SpecificDelegate()
{
    return null;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work - I get the following error:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'object[]'
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a `[Factory]` instead, see the [docs about it](http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3adata-driven_testing%3afactory) for more information.